# In Chrome, CSS3 animation on element with changing visibility gets played only when hidden

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations

See this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mMrl3lfCe7hFRawsoF4R?p=preview):

Assume an animated (CSS3) element is visible when the page is loaded. When you toggle it's visibility (visible/hidden) the animation will stop playing. If you pay closer attention you'll see that it's actually playing when the element is hidden and stops playing when it's visible.

This problem goes away if the element is set to `visibility:hidden` when the page is loaded and only then switched to visible.

Here's my simple jquery code for switching classes

```
$(function(){
  $("body").click(function(){
    if($(".busy-content").hasClass("on")){
      $(".busy-content").removeClass("on");
    }else{
      $(".busy-content").addClass("on");
    }
  });
});
```

And here is the CSS (copied from another app):

```
.busy-content{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.busy-content.on{
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:1;
}
```

It's a very strange behavior that doesn't repeat itself in IE/Edge/FF. Is this a Chrome bug? Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks!
E

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `.toggle()`. Here is the updated [fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/lJA15jYFoFofsnYOw1FC?p=preview) and it is working in chrome.

jQuery Code

```
$(function(){
  $("body").click(function(){
    //if($(".busy-content").hasClass("on")){
      //$(".busy-content").removeClass("on");
    //}else{
     // $(".busy-content").addClass("on");
    //}
    $(".busy-content").toggle();
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks. But that wasn't what I was trying to show. Toggle switches the display property. Not the visibility one. The idea is to have this element fade in and out so it's more pleasing to the eye.